# Iotivity iOS reference links. Steps to install Iotivity framework on Mac

Tags: ios, macos, iotivity

I'm trying to build iOS sample application using Iotivity framework. I followed the steps given in official [instruction](https://wiki.iotivity.org/ios_build_instructions) to install. I've stuck on the third step, the following command:

```
cp ~/boost.build/ios/framework/boost.framework ~/iotivity-ios-port/extlibs/boost/ios/framework/
```

Is executed with the error:

> path not found.

Is there any sample projects to understand this?

Comment: Can you please give us all output from your shell from the very beginning? Probably you have made a mistake somewhere. It's hard to help you without this information.

Comment: @manideep I see you are using copy command ,but where is file that you want to copy at destination path ? Moreover what is this ) in end of path, and are you sure this is correct path?

Comment: @Tusar, ")" is not an issue. It was my mistype when I have edited original post. Please disregard this brace.

Comment: @DJ-Glock no issues mate.

Comment: @manideep from the tutorial above have you completed second step successfully?

Comment: Hi Tushar. I've downloaded boost.sh file manually. I've added that to home directory manually. I got boost.framework also

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions don't look very useful, they may be outdated (although they're only a year old, looks like).  Have you followed other steps elsewhere for setting up your environment (git clone, etc)?  Does the path you are copying to exist (if you take the literal instruction, the git tree has to be at ~/iotivity-ios-port)? I would actually expect that boost needs to be added to xcode to be useful to the build, rather than have a local copy in extlibs.

Comment: Hi Mats.I tried for links that demonstrate how to create sample Iotivity application for iOS. But I found nothing. Could you provide any resource if possible how to create a sample Iotivity application for iOS

Comment: I'll see what I can find. You may want to jump over to the iotivity mailing list, there's more response there than happens here.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help you.

1. change "/iotivity-ios-port" folder as your iotivity path.
2. and make ios/framework.

For example, I use Iotivity folder than use like below.

1. I go to Iotivity forder.
2. I find Iotivity/extlibs/boost
3. I make two folder ios and framework which has same path as below.
4. in console, I do 
   `cp ~/boost.build/ios/framework/boost.framework ~/iotivity-ios-port/extlibs/boost/ios/framework/`